# Solution to small files bottleneck in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, apache-nifi

I have hundreds of thousands of small csv files in hdfs. Before merging them into a single dataframe, I need to add an id to each file individually (or else in the merge it won't be possible to distinguish between data from different files).

Currently I am relying on yarn to distribute the processes that I create that add the id to each file and convert to parquet format. I find that no matter how I tune the cluster (in size/executor/memory) that the bandwidth is limited at 2000-3000 files/h.

```
for i in range(0,numBatches):
    fileSlice = fileList[i*batchSize:((i+1)*batchSize)]
    p = ThreadPool(numNodes)

    logger.info('\n\n\n --------------- \n\n\n')
    logger.info('Starting Batch : ' + str(i))
    logger.info('\n\n\n --------------- \n\n\n')
    p.map(lambda x: addIdCsv(x), fileSlice)

def addIdCsv(x):
    logId=x[logId]
    filePath=x[filePath]
    fLogRaw = spark.read.option("header", "true").option('inferSchema', 'true').csv(filePath)
    fLogRaw = fLogRaw.withColumn('id', F.lit(logId))
    fLog.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(filePath + '_added')
```

You can see that my cluster is underperforming on CPU. But on the YARN manager it is given 100% access to resources.
[image]

What is the best was to solve this part of a data pipeline? What is the bottleneck?

**Update 1**
The jobs are evenly distributed as you can see in the event timeline visualization below.
[image]

Comment: This is an old entry but it's still true https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/

Comment: how many tasks do you have in the read stage (do you have a task per file)? What is the distribution of task duration?

Comment: Yes I have one process per file read. Task distribution is even.

Comment: @eliasah if hadoop really can't handle more than 50 concurrent read/write processes, I guess the small file problem is really fundamental to hadoop. I would have to look for another framework for this part of the pipeline. Does that make sense?

Comment: I believe that plain python would be more suitable.

Comment: CSV in Hadoop doesn't make sense, personally. Parquet or ORC are far better. A bunch of small CSV is even worse... At least use Bz2 archives that hold a lot of those files. If all those files fit on a single hard drive, though, Dask or Pandas would be better. And I if you still have to push data to HDFS, then one idea would be to buffer the data in Kafka or Nifi, then feed it out in larger batches to HDFS

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think you understand my use case. My end goal is parquet in hdfs that can merged into optimal partitions. The problem is the preprocessing step where each file has to be modified with a unique identifier (ex: filename) in order that the merge parquet files still allow the data to be grouped by the identifier. I have too many csvs for Pandas or Dask.

Comment: Okay, fine. I still think Nifi would be beneficial to provide that type of operation

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks I'm exploring a solution in Nifi. If you have experience, you can help me out with some of the S3 prefix issues I'm experiencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728387/nifi-lists3-nested-prefix-not-queuing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @cricket_007 suggestion, Nifi provides a good easy solution to this problem which is more scalable and integrates better with other frameworks than plain python. The idea is to read the files into Nifi before writing to hdfs (in my case they are in S3). There is still an inherent bottleneck of reading/writing to S3 but has a throughput around 45k files/h.

The flow looks like this.
[image: Nifi Flow]

Most of the work is done in the ReplaceText processor that finds the end of line character '|' and adds the uuid and a newline.
[image: ReplaceText Processor]